# No rules found using Apriori algorithm in R

Tags: r, apriori

I am trying to learn using R and frequent pattern mining and hence tried running apriori algorithm using arules package but there are no rules being generated. The output I get is listed below.
Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
rules <- apriori(data, parameter= list(supp=0.4, conf=0.4))

parameter specification:  
confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target
    0.4    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE     0.4      1     10  rules
ext
FALSE

algorithmic control:
filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

apriori - find association rules with the apriori algorithm
version 4.21 (2004.05.09)        (c) 1996-2004   Christian Borgelt
set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[6 item(s), 7 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inputs look fine. Probably it could not find any rules with the constraints on your support and confidence. Try having a very low support and confidence values like ~0.01 (and start with a max length of 2-3 rules so that R doesn't take your full memory). and see if it gives you any result. If it doesn't give you any result even then, probably there is something wrong with your data set. What are the attributes of your data?